# Differential equations, real time measurements of variables, and ML

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, prediction

**TL;DR**: We measure variable $x$ every $10$ minutes, solve a differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ where $y=f(x)$. We are interested in the time it takes for the cumulative value of $y$ to reach a certain value. Let's call that the output $z$. We can repeat the experiment multiple times to get the $z$ for various sequences of measured $x$. Which type of ML model might be best suited to predict $z$ from an ongoing measurement of $x$ in real-time.

---

We have a differential equation,

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ where $y=f(x)$

(We know the value of $y$ at time $t=0$, $y_{t=0}$.)

**Tricky part**: $x$ is measured in real-time. We get a measurement of its value every $10$ minutes.

x data:

| t (min) | x (units) |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $x_{t=0} = 0.1$ |
| $10$ | 0.3 |
| $20$ | 0.25 |
| ' | ' |
| ' | ' |

Because of this we solve the differential equation at time steps of $10$ minutes and use the value of $y$ at the end of each step as the starting value for the next step.

| t (min) | Starting value of y | Solution of diff. equ<sup>n</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0-10$ | $y_{t=0}$ | $y_{t=10}$ |
| $10-20$ | $y_{t=10}$ | $y_{t=20}$ |
| $20-30$ | $y_{t=20}$ | $y_{t=30}$ |
| ' | ' | ' |
| ' | ' | ' |

As a result, we have $y$ vs $t$ corresponding to real-time measurements of $x$.

Next, we calculate values of cumulative $y$ vs $t$, and define $z$ as the value of $t$ at which the value of cumulative $y$ reaches a pre-decided threshold value.

Based on all of that, we have our final data,

| t (min) | x (units) | z (min) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0.1$ | $180$ |
| $10$ | $0.3$ |  |
| $20$ | $0.25$ |  |
| ' | ' |  |
| ' | ' |  |
| $180$ | ' |  |

We can repeat this experiment multiple times and generate values of $z$ for various sequences of $x$.

**Question**: What ML model do you think would be better suited for such data? Our *objective* is to be able to predict $z$ for ongoing real-life measurements of $x$.

Comment: This is quite confusing, have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you for pointing that out, but I can't figure how else to ask the question. I think it only sounds like an XY problem but isn't one. I've added a tl;dr section which is the only way I think I can make it sound less like an XY problem.